# printf incorrect output for doubles

Tags: c, floating-point, double, printf

I compute two numbers using a CPU and a GPU. They are both double precision floating point numbers.
When I print them using printf I get:

```
CPU=11220648352037704534577864266910298593595406193008158076631751727790009102214012225556499863999825039525639767460911091800702910643896210872459798230329601182926117099298535084878987264.00000 GPU=-4.65287
```

using:

```
void print(const double *data1, const double *data2) {
    ...
    printf("CPU=%.5f\tGPU=%.5f\n", data1[k], data2[k]);
}
```

Which is way to many digits I would expect. Why do I get this? Do I overflow, underflow, corrupt memory? Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: can you inform us what is `k`?

Comment: You are sure that you initialized `data1[k]` ??

Comment: are they `long double`?

Comment: @Streppel `k` is an integer index into the array, definitely within bounds.
They are not `long doubles` and yes, they are definitely initialized.

Comment: Check `data1[k]` with the debugger.

Comment: What happens if you use just `%f`instead of `%.5f` ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz I checked with the debugger and got `1.1220648352037705e+184` which indeed seems to got a bit big. Is it possible that an underflow/overflow caused this?

Comment: 1.1e+184 is within the valid range of a double. Anything might have lead to this value.

Comment: You asked for a decimal value with 5 digits after the comma, ´printf(3)´ obliges. Use an exponential format.

Comment: "Which is way to many digits I would expect.". OK, what did you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the printf format `%.5f`.  That means "print plain decimal digits all the way down to five places after the decimal."  If you want scientific notation instead, which is more common with such large numbers, you should use `%.5g`, which means "print automatic format digits all the way down to five places after the decimal...or really four places in scientific notation."

Note that such huge numbers as you have are definitely within range for a `double`.  There is nothing unusual about the value of the number in the code you have posted.

Comment: Thanks, this is not my problem though. I want to know what is wrong with this number as it is meant to be the same as the GPUs. Also, is this not too many digits for a double precision number to have?

Comment: @user1096294 TBH, The answer is for your question as you did ask it.   Now you are asking another question. You never said the numbers should be the same. And yes it is ok as explained, they just might be not exactly precise after 14 or 15 significant place.

Comment: @user1096294: you have not given us any information relevant to the problem then.  You might consider if what we've told you here has taught you something new, then just accept an answer to this question and start a new one with your actual issue.  Which would then need to include sufficient code to reproduce the problem of why you have mismatched results.  There's no way for us to know now.  A `double` has about 15 digits of accuracy, but you can print it with as many digits as you like!

Comment: The proper way to dispose of this question is to delete it, not to accept an answer. It is only noise on the site.